# How to save address bar history from any browser (Chrome, Mozilla, etc.)

Tags: google-chrome, history

I'm working on a MBP running 10.12.x but this would also be good to know for my Windows box too.

My MBP is dying and IT is copying all my data from the old MBP to the new MBP.  However, this doesn't include settings or history.  I want to save all the addresses from my Chrome and Mozilla because there are work servers that I frequently visit and I don't want to have to look them all up again.  I there a way to copy my old address bar history from the old MBP to the new MBP so I can type in a partial name and it will pop up?

I found tons of links in google to delete links from their address bar that autocompletes but thru the first few pages of search results, I haven't found anything that saves/preserves the history.

Comment: Just transferring the browser's user profile is enough, but looking how to do it for every browser, is way to broad

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks.  I was in the middle of copying my user profile over when I noticed the Chrome on my new MBP had all the links in the addr and my bookmarks, without me exporting/importing them.  I think it somehow thru my acct linked them.  Lucky me.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have to copy over anything.  I don't know what settings are selected on my gmail account but it transferred over my historical address bar urls and bookmarks.  Lucky me.  If I find those settings, I'll update my answer but for now, it looks like Google does it for you.

Found this link here from Chrome regarding syncing:
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Chrome and Firefox have account syncing